# binary longitudinal time series

Tags: time-series, feature-engineering, binary

What kind of feature engineering techniques should one apply for longitudinal data comprising of individual binary time interval data about when an activity was done during the day(we have this data for every person in our database) with each interval being represented by the starting and end time ?

I have thought about pre classifying people into number of logical groups and then for each group dividing the entire day into slots of fixed interval and then in each slot finding:

- number of people in that sub group that started that activity in that slot
- number of people in that sub group that ended that activity in that slot

I have also thought about finding average number of time that each group spends in a day performing that activity, and repeat the above process for all days

---

Do we have some existing research that address this kind of data?

Comment: What's the ultimate goal?

Comment: @Emre To model the presence of people at a location which can be further used to deduce interesting information. This will be particularly helpful in places like retail shops or shoping malls